# Automatically run a self extracting .exe with a /T command line switch?

Tags: windows, installation, self-extracting

I want to distribute a self extracting executable that will extract to a hard coded directory with no user prompting. Right now, I'm using iexpress to package up my files, but I can't figure out how to automatically extract them without a dialog coming up asking the user to specify a destination folder.

Essentially, I want the automatic version of the [/T option](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197147) that happens when the user double clicks on the .exe file. How would I go about doing this? In a related matter, is there something I can do to an arbitrary executable to make it so that double clicking on it runs it with a command line switch (I know how to do this with shortcuts, but I don't know how to do this with the actual executable)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [IExpress page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346760.aspx), you can use an option in the [.INF file](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/ie/ieak/techinfo/deploy/60/en/INFDOC.mspx) to specify silent install mode.